# equation is not the equation of a circle

Tags: circles

I can see the following equation is not the equation of a circle because it has a y term and no ${y^2}$ term but how would I better explain this is not an equation of a circle:

${x^2 + 8x -16y -1 = 0}$

Comment: Imagine $x$ very large. You can find a $y$ satisfying the equation, so the curve is unbounded, unlike circles.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that a parabola is not a circle?

Comment: A circle is a circle is a circle.Of course you are allowed that.Otherwise you  wouldn't know what a circle is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make x and y arbitrarily large.  (I'd make this a comment, but I don't have enough reputation).

Comment: Actually this is about as much of an answer as this question needs.